# Powershell to get template name site is using

Tags: powershell

I have a site collection `http:/SC/` under which I have a site `http:/SC/site`. Can you provide powershell to check which template `http:/SC/site` is using?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http:/SC/site
$web.WebTemplate + " " + $web.WebTemplateId
$web.close()
```

Comment: I got the result "SAHREDSERVICEPROJECT" and template ID can I get my template display name also? or any way to check which template display name has this ID

Comment: You can use `Get-SPWebTeamplate`, e.g., `Get-SPWebTemplate | ? { $_.Name -like "*SAHREDSERVICEPROJECT*" }`

Comment: Alternatively, on one line:
`Get-SPWeb -Site "http://sc" | select Title, URL, WebTemplate, WebTemplateId`
or, get all webs in a site:
`Get-SPSite | Get-SPWeb | select Title, URL, WebTemplate, WebTemplateId`

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is only partly correct.
If the question was to get the name of the used web template, the correct answer would be:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http:/SC/site
$web.WebTemplate + "#" + $web.Configuration
```

It seems, Microsoft had an issue (or later added requirement) when implementing these templates, because there is a "background"-id (`$web.WebTemplateId`) which presumably denotes the base template used - and there is a "foreground"-id (`$web.Configuration`) which is added to the template name, delimited by the **#** sign.

If you use Get-SPWebTemplate, you can see that all the three STS Templates have the same "background"-id but different "foreground"-ids in their name:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-SPWebTemplate -Identity "STS#0" | Select-Object Name,Id

Name  ID
----  --
STS#0  1


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-SPWebTemplate -Identity "STS#1" | Select-Object Name,Id

Name  ID
----  --
STS#1  1


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-SPWebTemplate -Identity "STS#2" | Select-Object Name,Id

Name  ID
----  --
STS#2  1
```

For Webs of all three types, using `$web.WebTemplateId` will always be 1 ("background"-id) and the value in `$web.Configuration` will vary according to the template and be 0, 1 or 2 ("foreground"-id).

So, to get the name of the used template, the correct field for the template number would be `$web.Configuration`, not `$web.WebTemplateId`.

Comment: This is correct. If you view source and search for g_wsaSiteTemplateId, the result is the same as the PowerShell above. Otherwise, you will always get #STS1.

Answer (score 1):

> PowerShell code to find the site template id and name

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://dmsApp/dept/ceo/
write-host "Web Template:" $web.WebTemplate " | Web Template ID:" $web.WebTemplateId
$web.Dispose()
```